# Corrupted files - all files on drive had their size capped to 64 KB

Tags: windows, filesystems, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption

I have a Windows hard-drive from my previous computer that got corrupted in a very weird manner.

**All the files in the hard-drive had their size capped to 64 KB** (I connected the hard-drive to my existing computer via an external adapter).
No files seem to be missing from this hard-drive, but file sizes range from 0 to 64 KB, but never more than that.
If a file was originally (before this happened) less than 64 KB, e.g. a small text file - I can view it normally and all is great.
If an image file was, say 4.7 MB, I see it as 64 KB, and when opening it in a photo viewer - it shows the image's first couple of rows of pixels, and then the rest of the image is corrupted.
Other file formats, e.g. a large DOCX file that now appears as 64 KB large cannot even be opened.

I don't know enough about Windows filesystem and how file-size is computed / stored in the file system,
but it seems like the table that stores the file-sizes somehow got corrupted, or maybe some other attribute of the hard-drive got corrupted, like the allocation unit size ? (shooting in the dark here).

It just seems like all the data is still in tact in the drive, but not reachable because the file sizes got messed up for anything over 64 KB.

Any help would be extremely appreciated !

Comment: To start, _which_ filesystem are you talking about? FAT32? NTFS?

Comment: Put the hard drive directly into the computer.  It is probably a translation issue with sector size and the external adaptor.  This is not an uncommon problem.

Comment: @davidgo - I'm probably missing something obvious. This drive was was a 'D:\' drive on my old Windows XP rig. I've put it in my newer Windows 10 machine (using an external HD adapter), and it seems like all the files have a capped size of 64KB. Are you suggesting the external adapter is the issue ? I've used it for lots of other drives that I have and they all show up in Windows 10 perfectly.

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting that the external adapter is most likely the problem, in as much as its reporting different drive geometry and stuffing things up. It is possible that the adaptor works fine for some drives but not others - and I've had some experience here...